# Zsh Performance: Should I create scripts or just add functions to a file I source in .zshrc?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, performance

I use a lot of little zsh functions. I have been adding them to a single functions.zsh file which I source in .zshrc.

If they are created as scripts, or autoloading is used, will that improve speed?

For the record, I'm much more at ease with my current approach.

What about bigger, say 100-line functions?

Answer (score 1):

Autoloading will improve the startup time. It won't have any influence on the runtime.

Whether it's a noticeable improvements depends on how much code you have, how fast your computer is and how impatient you are.